How to model data with "super failures"?
In the radial arm water maze, an animal is placed in one arm of an (in this case) 8-armed maze with bait in one other arm. After some training, the animal is then observed making further attempts. A commonly used outcome is "percent accuracy", which is the number of times the animal enters the correct arm divided by the number of times the animal enters any arm. However, in a recent set of results I was handed, some animals never enter any arms. They just float or paddle around. I am calling these "super failures", where their "accuracy" would normally be determined as zero divided by zero--that won't work. Normally, I'd model this as count data with an offset, but can this be done in such a case? Is it valid to use zero-inflated modeling if both the count and the offset are zero? I'm guessing not. What do I do in such a case?
Could I manually do a hurdle model with the second model having the zero-offset instances deleted?

The standard "percent accuracy" measure might not be appropriate here. You have to decide whether you care about the overall probability of making a correct choice or the probability of making a correct choice given that a choice was made. The "percent accuracy" you describe seems to be the latter, while (at least to me) the overall probability of making a correct choice would seem more important.
This is similar to what happens in a competing-risk survival model where the interest is in the time to an event: choosing the "correct" arm is one outcome state, choosing an "incorrect" arm is another outcome state, and an individual that hasn't yet made a choice at the end of the trial remains in the initial state (no choice) with a right censored event time.
If you have recorded the times of the choices for each trial, then a survival model might be even more informative. The R competing risks vignette discusses the issues. You need to model all states together, however. You can use mixed models, frailty approaches, or robust standard errors to handle the repeated measures on the same animal.
If you only have correct/incorrect/none outcomes without time information, then your suggested hurdle model would be OK provided that you interpret and present the results carefully. You first model the probability of making any choice, and then model the correct/incorrect outcome probability given that a choice was made.
You need to present all of those models together, however, and distinguish the probability of making a correct choice overall from the probability of making the correct choice given that a choice was made. I think that your hurdle model would be equivalent to a multinomial model for the three outcome categories (correct/incorrect/none), from which you might more readily get probabilities for all 3 states as a function of your experimental conditions.
